# Component Art WebChart causing Asp.net worker thread memory leak

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks, componentart, webchartcontrol

We are using the Component Art WebChart for an online dynamic report and after 1 or 2 page loads of the report it throws the memory into a tail spin.  The WP3 worker thread just goes to about 400mb and climbing and finally low memory and the system either requires a hard boot or if we can do an iisreset in time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a memory leak... it's an infinite loop or stack overflow somewhere.  Trim a test page down to the bare necessity for WebChart to determine if the problem is really internal to their control.  If it is, then you're on the wrong web site.  I've found their support to be fairly good in the past.